# Error: Cannot find module ‘/opt/Ferdi/resources/app.asar/node_modules/@meetfranz/theme/lib/index.js’

Tags: javascript, python, electron, chromium

I’m collaborating with the programmers involved in the ferdi project.

https://getferdi.com/

Ferdi motto is :"All your messaging services in one place ". Infact it is like franz and it works on a lot of oses,such as mac os M1,windows,ubuntu x64 bit. And we are trying to make it work also on the arm64 / jetson nano / Tegra. Unfortunately on this os it does not work correctly because we have a javascript error that we aren’t able to fix. This is how to reproduce it :

```
[ `root@zi-desktop` ](mailto:root@zi-desktop) `:~/Desktop/zi/Work/I9/Virt/dockers/arm64/ferdi2# ferdi`

`[21980:0709/185715.104381:FATAL:electron_main_delegate.cc(252)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See` [ `https://crbug.com/638180` ](https://crbug.com/638180) `.Trace/breakpoint trap`

[ `root@zi-desktop` ](mailto:root@zi-desktop) `:~/Desktop/zi/Work/I9/Virt/dockers/arm64/ferdi2# ferdi --no-sandbox`

`A JavaScript error occurred in the main processUncaught Exception:Error: Cannot find module` [ `'/opt/Ferdi/resources/app.asar/node_modules/@meetfranz` ](mailto:'/opt/Ferdi/resources/app.asar/node_modules/@meetfranz) `/theme/lib/index.js'.
 Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entryat 
tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:310:19)at 
Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:523:18)at 
Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:874:27)at 
Function.n._resolveFilename (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:257:1128)at 
Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:27)at Function.f._load 
(electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12913)`
```

(running as normal user gives the same error)

Basically we use a docker container like this to produce the deb packages that we will install on the os . Below u can see the Dockerfile for arm64 / tegra / jetson nano :

```
`FROM node:fermium-buster`

`LABEL Author="ZioMario <` [ `marietto2008@gmail.com` ](mailto:marietto2008@gmail.com) `>"`

`LABEL Title="arm64/ferdi"`

`# Enviorment variables`

`#ARG username=ferdi-arm64-builder`

`#ENV HOME /home/$username`

`ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`

`ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8`

`ENV LANG=C.UTF-8`

`ENV PATH="/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/local/lib:/usr/include:/usr/share"`

`#ENV HW="GPU"`

`#ENV TERM xterm`

`ENV USE_SYSTEM_FPM=true`

`ENV PREVAL_BUILD_INFO_PLACEHOLDERS=true`

`#RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl netbase wget tzdata rpm git xz-utils nano gedit ruby gem`

`RUN apt-get update && apt install -y rpm ruby gem && gem install fpm --no-ri --no-rdoc --no-document`

`WORKDIR /ferdi`

`RUN git clone` [ `https://github.com/getferdi/ferdi.git` ](https://github.com/getferdi/ferdi.git) `. && git submodule update --init --recursive`

`RUN npx lerna bootstrap`

`RUN cd recipes && npm i && npm run package`

`RUN npm run build`
```

It is working everywhere,except on the jetson nano. do u have some ideas about how to fix it ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases usually try to delete the `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`, then try to run `npm install` again.

Also looks like you have a problem related to the `"main"` prop in `package.json`. The main property of a `package.json` is a direction to the entry point to the module that the `package.json` is describing.

For example in a Node.js application, when the module is called via a required statement, the module's exports from the file named in the main property will be what's returned to the Node.js application.